# PHP not displaying results from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display an entry from a MySql database which is selected by GET data.

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])){

        $id=$_GET["id"];
        $result = getSelectedBlog($id); 

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            { 
                extract($row); 
                ?>

                    <div class="headline"><?php echo $headline ?></div>
                    <div class="subtitle"><?php echo $subTitle ?></div>
                    <div class="content"><?php echo $content ?></div>
                    <?php
            }
```

Here is the SQL statement:

```
function getSelectedBlog($id){

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'michaelWebsite') or die('could not connect');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE "$id"';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('entry does not exist.:' . mysqli_error($con)); 
return $result;
```

}

As you can see, I am passing the get data as $id to the method that returns the result. However nothing is being returned. There are three entries at the moment, if I change $id in the SQL statement to either 1, 2 or 3 it will show the corresponding data but it just will not work with the $id variable.

The URL does end with the correct info ?id=1.

Please excuse me if it is something stupid, I have just been stuck on this for hours now!!

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($id);` inside the function to see what it is.

Comment: You've got an SQL injection hole in your code - directly using `$_GET['id']` within the query. Read [this](http://bobby-tables.com) before you go ANY FURTHER with this code.

Comment: You are using mysqli_* functions as if they were mysql_* functions. Try escaping the $id, your code is vulnerable to mysql injection ($id comes from $_GET, is not sanitized, and is inserted right into the query. Get your hands on a good mysql/mysqli/pdo&mysql tutorial. I recommend you go for PDO&MySQL. Good luck.

Comment: You're also using single quotes for your query string, which do NOT interpolate variables. You're trying to find a literal `$id` in your DB.

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` when you want an exact match. Use `=` instead. Like is slower, it's for searches with wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these answers will solve your problem, but none have mentioned or prevented [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

In your case I recommend (assuming `articleID` is an integer field).

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE "' . (int)$id . '"';
```

I'm also curious why you are using `LIKE` for an *id* field.

**Note:** Since you are using MySQLi, I'd encourage you to look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE "'.$id.'"';
```

escape your var in simple quote

Comment: You should also escape it from SQL Injection. In this case, you could simply cast it.

Comment: Yes use mysql_real_escape_string() or a DAO class like pdo for example

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE '$id'";
```

or with

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE "' . $id . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes in order for php to correctly expand your variables :) so change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE "$id"'
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM tblArticle WHERE tblArticle.articleID LIKE '$id'"
```

Variables will be evaluated only if they're between double quotes `"`